# Django large file upload (.dcm)

Tags: python, django, file-upload, dropzone.js

After the user starts uploading files of 1-2 gb on a page in Django, I want the user to be able to navigate on other pages while the upload process continues. How can I do it?

I can upload the files to the server with the chunk method and merge them in the back. However, this upload process is interrupted when I switch to other pages. I want this to continue without interruption.

I tried to create a structure with Django channels and send files with the chunking method of dropzone.js, but I failed. Only string data was sent. I also could not convert the chunk .dcm data to base64.

I did not try the celery method. I just searched for its possibility, but I could not find anything clear.

```
autoProcessQueue: false,
url: url,
maxFiles: 100000000,
maxFilesize: 99999,
acceptedFiles: '.dcm',
timeout: 9999999999,
chunking: true,
chunkSize: 2000000,
clickable: "#dicomDropzone",
parallelChunkUploads: false,
retryChunks: true,
retryChunksLimit: 5,
forceChunking: true,
init: function() {  
    $('#CBCTUpload').click(function(){      
        myDropzone2.processQueue();
    })
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        totalAddedFiles++;
    });
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('slug', parametre);
    });
}


    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.FILES:
            return HttpResponse(status=500)
        file = request.FILES['file']
        print("FILE", file.name)
        
        current_chunk = int(request.POST['dzchunkindex']) + 1
        total_chunks = int(request.POST['dztotalchunkcount'])
        dzchunkbyteoffset = int(request.POST['dzchunkbyteoffset'])
        folder_slug = request.POST.get('slug')
```

Comment: How are channels going to help? The problem is on the frontend, the browser will cancel the upload if you navigate away from the page making the request. If you have an SPA then you could browse around different screens in your app, but navigating away to a different site will still cancel the upload

Comment: @Anentropic ty for ur comment. By browsing pages, I mean that I want to navigate the pages within my own website, for example, I want to continue an upload process that I started on the homepage on the report page and view the upload.

Comment: for that to work you need to have SPA-style "fake navigation" where navigating the site is all done via JS, i.e. you click a link and JS makes an XHR request to backend to fetch new data, JS replaces current page content, JS updates the browser address bar location to look like you navigated to a new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPA (Single Page Application) using react or Angualr can help you in this but this can't be done in Django, as Django depends on request-response lifecycle especially if you are using Django templates.